# find occurrences of char case insensitive code wars

Tags: javascript

Check to see if a string has the same amount of 'x's and 'o's. The method must return a boolean and be case insensitive. The string can contain any char.

Someone posted their answer is like this but I don't understand the part x && x.length. Can someone explain this?

```
function XO(str) {
  let x = str.match(/x/gi);
  let o = str.match(/o/gi);
  return (x && x.length) === (o && o.length);
}
```

Comment: `x && x.length` means "x is truthy and x.length is truthy".  "truthy" means not equal to `null`, `undefined`, `0` or `""`.  In modern JS the same thing could be done with `x?.length`.

Answer (score 0):

`str.match(/x/gi)` returns an array of matches if there are any matches. But if there aren't any matches, it returns `null`. You can't get the `length` of `null`, so `x && x.length` makes use of short-circuiting to prevent that error. It will be `null` if `x === null`, otherwise it will be the lenth of the array.

The same goes for `o && o.length`. So if both return matches, it compares the number of matches. If both have zero matches, it turns into `null === null`, which is true. And if only one of them has matches, `null` will not be equal to the length of the matches.

Comment: tks so much for ur answer. I just wondering in this x.length means it counts the occurrences of all 'x'?

Comment: Yes. when you use the `g` flag with a regexp, `match()` returs all the matches in an array, so the length is the count of occurrences.